# How do I hook up a murano chandelier to a three wire service

Tags: light

Chandelier It has a brown and blue wire coming out of it not three

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of the wires you're hoping to connect to? And, what used to be there?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: 3-way switch setup? 2 light switches (in different areas) that control this 1 light?

Answer (score 0):

Standard color codes outside North America are

- Brown for hot
- Blue for neutral

If the chandelier is metal, you can ground to the metal chassis.   I assume by "three wire service" you mean hot, neutral and safety ground.  If you mean 2 hots and a neutral, you'll need to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ohm meter or a continuity light to insure the brown wire is hot by testing from the brown wire to the light fixture where the bulb screws in there is a little "tab" or "button" that contacts the bottom tip of the light bulb, any reading with the ohm meter proves there is a circuit or continuity, same applies with the continuity light, it will glow if there is continuity. Test from the fixtures threaded section the bulb screws into to the blue wire to insure it is for neutral.
In days past it was kosher to make a "bootleg" ground by using the neutral wire to ground the fixture assuming it is metal, this is not code any longer it was done for 220v electric dryers with 110v timer motors or ovens with clock motors etc.
The problem is that although the ground and neutral bars in the service panel are common, meaning they are connected, it is not kosher to connect ground to neutral any place beyond the service panel.
I would test from the fixture itself to insure no continuity from the neutral wire to the fixtures metallic structure, assuming there is no continuity you should use the ground wire to ground the fixtures metal structure since you have no 3rd wire coming from the fixture.

Comment: Hello yet again. This is a good answer, and thanks. Keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

Brown is phase, blue is neutral, there's no green-yellow because the chandelier is class II and do not need it, just cap the PE wire coming from ceiling. In any case check in the 'glass' that covers the ceiling box if there's a metal post where you can connect PE on, if present it should have the ground symbol on.

If in your ceiling you have 3 wires, none being PE (green-yellow or bare copper), the case should be investigated deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Being that Murano chandeliers are all glass, there would be nothing to attach a ground wire to, nor any reason. If there is a metal bracket included in the chandelier, attach the ground wire to that with a screw. But other than that as the others have said, Blue = Neutral (White wire in North America), Brown = Hot (Black or Red wire in North America).